# Output error is 0x03BB7390

Tags: python, algorithm

```
def fastMaxVal(w, v, i, aW):
    global numCalls
    numCalls += 1
    try: return m[(i, aW)]
    except KeyError:
        if i == 0:
            if w[i] <= aW:
                m[(i, aW)] = v[i]
                return v[i]
            else:
                m[(i, aW)] = 0
                return 0
        without_i = fastMaxVal(w, v, i-1, aW)
        if w[i] > aW:
            m[(i, aW)] = without_i
            return without_i
        else:
            with_i = v[i] + fastMaxVal(w, v, i-1, aW - w[i])
        res = max(with_i, without_i)
        m[(i, aW)] = res
        return res

def maxVal0(w, v, i, aW):
    m = {}
    return fastMaxVal

weights = [1, 1, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4]
vals = [15, 15, 10, 10, 9, 9, 5, 5]
numCalls = 0
res = maxVal0(weights, vals, len(vals) - 1, 8)
print ('max Val =', res, 'number of calls =', numCalls)
```

The program is about 01Knapsack problem. I use the decision tree to solve the problem. However, I ran the program and got the following result.

> max Val = function fastMaxVal at 0x03BB7390 number of calls = 0

What's wrong with my program?

Comment: This is not an error. You are simply returning the *function* `fastMaxVal` from `maxVal0`. You have to *call the function*.

Comment: Please say what language you're using, and reduce the error to just the code that's causing the problem.  It's also helpful to see what you were _expecting_ your code to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `maxVal0` function you're returning the `fastMaxVal` function itself, instead of its call result.

I think it should be like this:

```
def maxVal0(w, v, i, aW):
    m = {}
    return fastMaxVal(w, v, i, aW)
```

Also, your `fastMaxVal` is using `m`, but it isn't in its scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fastMaxVal(w, v, i, aW, m):
    global numCalls
    numCalls += 1
    try: return m[(i, aW)]
    except KeyError:
        if i == 0:
            if w[i] <= aW:
                m[(i, aW)] = v[i]
                return v[i]
            else:
                m[(i, aW)] = 0
                return 0
        without_i = fastMaxVal(w, v, i-1, aW, m)
        if w[i] > aW:
            m[(i, aW)] = without_i
            return without_i
        else:
            with_i = v[i] + fastMaxVal(w, v, i-1, aW - w[i], m)
        res = max(with_i, without_i)
        m[(i, aW)] = res
        return res

def maxVal0(w, v, i, aW):
    m = {}
    return fastMaxVal(w, v, i, aW, m)

weights = [1, 1, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4]
vals = [15, 15, 10, 10, 9, 9, 5, 5]
numCalls = 0
res = maxVal0(weights, vals, len(vals) - 1, 8)
print ('max Val =', res, 'number of calls =', numCalls)
```

I put the right on the above. And I attached the result as follows.

> max Val = 48 number of calls = 50